# Tag merge suggestion: [calf] and [calves]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are not a lot of questions on either tag, but it's about the same muscle group. It would make sense to merge both [calf](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calf) and [calves](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed.

I will allow some time for someone else to chime in before merging them though.

EDIT: Merged. Thanks for the suggestion, Luciano.

Comment: I can't see any reason not to.